# Plotting many points makes my computer freeze

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib

I'm writing a python script to plot some random data that I generate. I have a file with my data, and when I load it and try to plot it, if I try to plot more than 1000 points, my pc will freeze giving a matplotlib error (I'd say which one but it just says error in a dialogue box and asks me to either force quit or wait, but most of the times it'll be impossibile to click anything), and I'm forced to restart.
I'm completely new to python, and I need this script to run with up to 100'000 or 1'000'000 points, is there a more efficient way? I don't know what I'm getting wrong, but I'd like my pc to stop freezing, below is my code

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File = open('RandomData.txt', 'r')
#File has 4 columns
Lines = File.readlines()
Data = [[],[],[],[]]
for I in range (0, 3):
    for Line in Lines :
        Data[I].append(Line.split()[I])
#Here I try to plot just the first set of random data, to see if it works
plt.plot(Data[0],Data[0]) 
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your numbers particularly big?

Comment: First column is line number, so the theorethical biggest is 1'000'000

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to with your script. I'm guessing you're running out of memory because with 16 GB of RAM I was able to plot 8 million points without too much trouble. I could probably have gone higher but it was already 8 times more data than you'd be plotting. How much RAM does your computer have?

Comment: Maybe it is due to the fact that you're trying to plot strings rather than integers... Try to convert your numbers into `int` before plotting them.

Comment: g2i I tried your solution and now it works perfect, thank you very much! If you make your comment as an answer I'll mark the post as solved.

Comment: @g2i: It would be a good idea to write this up as an answer and have it accepted so that others would have better awareness to this as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @tom10 and the OP, I put this as an answer for further reference.

The problem was that the list contained `str` instead of integers. Casting them to `int` solved the problem.